# SignalR not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to do some stuff with the signalr.
My hub is

```
 public class Customer : SignalR.Hubs.Hub
{
    public void Send(string uid, string from, string msg)
    {
        string make = from + uid;
        Clients.Addmsg(msg, make);
    }
}
```

And Client side code is

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var care = $.connection.Customer;

        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            // Call the chat method on the server
            care.send($('#msg').val(), "HariOm", "jai jai ram")
        .done(function () {
            console.log('Success!');
        })
        .fail(function (e) {
            console.warn(e);
        });
        });

    // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
    care.Addmsg = function (message, make) {
        alert(message + msg);
    };



        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();


    });


</script>
```

I am getting this error after loading the page

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Addmsg' of undefined

Comment: Try it with lowercase hub name: e.g. `var care = $.connection.customer;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that the name of the hub on the client-side should be lowercase, as the proxy generation generates the hub name in camel case. So your proxy should look like:

```
 var care = $.connection.customer;
```

That is why you are getting the error that your `care` object is undefined. This is documented on the [SignalR Wiki - JS Client Hubs](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs) page. Also if you look at the generated `/signalr/hubs` page in your browser, you will see the hub and its methods defined.

Comment: parameter names should also be same  as they declared in the hub ?

Comment: Most of the examples show using the same parameter names, but so long as they are the same type, they should work. But I cannot say for sure.

Comment: @PaigeCook I also had trouble with capital letter of hub classes thanks for explanation